# Text in Silverlight Textblock keeps changing its size as text changes

Tags: silverlight, text, silverlight-4.0, textblock

I am writing a counter app in silverlight and using a textblock to display seconds. Whenever the second is changing for example from 01 to 01 and so on the first digit (0) moves a littlebit as the width of the seconds digit changes.

I would like to find out, if there is a settings somewhere, where I can force the digits in my textblock to occupy always the same amount of space, so if one of them is changing the other is not moved around.

Comment: Is this Silverlight 5? If yes, try to set `Typography.NumeralAlignment="Tabular"` on the `TextBlock`

Comment: No. It is not Silverlight 5. It is v4, but thanks for the suggestion